# Почему ошибка компилятора для перегруженного оператора-члена * в классе?

Tags: c++, ооп, функции, классы, visual-c++

Вот класс:

```
class Mat4 {
public:
float m[4][4];

Mat4();
Mat4( const float val );
Mat4( const float _11, const float _12, const float _13, const float _14,
const float _21, const float _22, const float _23, const float _24,
const float _31, const float _32, const float _33, const float _34,
const float _41, const float _42, const float _43, const float _44 );

float & operator()( const int x, const int y );
float * operator()(){ return &m[0][0]; }

Mat4 & operator*( const Mat4 & mat );
Mat4 & operator*=( const Mat4 & mat );

static const Mat4 & rotation( const float & pitch, const float & roll, const float & yaw );
static const Mat4 & translation( const float & x, const float & y, const float & z );
static const Mat4 & translation( const Vec3 & trans );
static const Mat4 & scale( const float x, const float y, const float z );
static const Mat4 & scale( const Vec3 & vecScal );
static const Mat4 & scale( const float allAxisScal );

static const Mat4 & perspProj( const float fov, const float aspect, const float near_plane, const float far_plane );
static const Mat4 & view( const Vec3 & position, const Vec3 & target, const Vec3 & up );

static const Mat4 identity;
};
```

Вот так пользуюсь:

```
Mat4 wvp =  Mat4 :: translation( 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f ) * Mat4 :: perspProj( M_PI / 3.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f );
```

Вот такая ошибка:

> Отсутствует оператор "*",
> соответствующий этим операторам. Типы
> операторов: const Mat4 * const Mat4

Почему так, ведь я перегрузил умножение?

P.S. компилятор VC++2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте объявить

```
Mat4 operator*( const Mat4 & mat ) const;
```

Объявленный вами `Mat4 & operator*( const Mat4 & mat )` не может быть использован, если левый операнд `const`. И если я правильно понимаю, в возвращаемом типе `&` не нужна.

В качестве альтернативы можно определить симметричный оператор:

```
static Mat4 operator*(const Mat4& lhs, const Mat4& rhs);
```